# Enviar archivo txt por WhatsApp

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy intentando enviar un archivo txt creado dentro de mi aplicacion a traves de WhatsApp, el codigo que tengo desarrollado es el siguiente

```
//guarda en el telefono
            FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(desde + "-" + hasta + " " + str_nombre + " " + str_apellido + ".txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            out.write((data.toString()).getBytes());
            out.close();
            File filelocation = new File(getFilesDir(), desde + "-" + hasta + " " + str_nombre + " " + str_apellido + ".txt");


        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(filelocation)));
            intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp no esta instalado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

No se que es lo que esta fallando, me dice que el tipo de archivo no es compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder enviar un archivo vía `WhatsApp`, actualmente debes usar un `FileProvider`.

Dentro de `/res` crea el directorio `/xml` y dentro el archivo `provider_paths.xml`. Debido a que usas `getFilesDir()` debes usar `<files-path` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>  
    <files-path  name="files" path="/"/> <!--root path is com.jorgesys.whatsappsendpdf/files/ -->
</paths>
```

dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` agrega la definición del provider, definiendo en `android:authorities` el paquete de tu aplicación.

```
  ...
  ...
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.jorgesys.sendfilewhatsapp"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Esta sería la forma correcta para enviar el archivo .txt usando WhatsApp, recuerda que es importante asegur que el archivo se haya creado correctamente mediante `file.exists()` :

```
  private void sendWhatsApp(){
        try {
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
            file.createNewFile(); //Create file
            if(file.exists()){ //file exists?
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(), fileName), true);
                out.write(("Buna sunt Jorgesys | 12345 67890").getBytes()); //Add info to file.
                out.close();
                Log.i(TAG, "add info to file: " + file.getCanonicalFile());
                try { // Send file via WhatsApp
                    Uri uriFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName(), file); //add  <files-path  name="files" path="/"/>
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriFile);
                    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp is not installed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can´t create file to send.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Te sugiero revisar este ejemplo que realicé:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Send-flle-WhatsApp